# How to add a new drive to a RAID (mdadm), when that RAID is encrypted (LUKS), and makes up a physical volume in a volume group (LVM)?

Tags: raid, lvm, mdadm, nas

I'm looking to add a new drive to an existing NAS server, and would appreciate a second look at my plan before I pull the trigger. Part of the challenge is the new disk will be added to an existing RAID, which itself is encrypted, and also makes up a physical-volume in an existing volume-group.

#### Current Setup:

There is a single logical-volume ('media') and volume-group ('raid') made up of two physical-volumes ('/dev/mapper/crypt1' and '/dev/mapper/crypt2'). Each physical-volume is a LUKS-encrypted RAID: a (1) RAID-5 made up of 4x4TB drives ('md0'), and a (2) RAID-1 made up of 2x8TB drives ('md127').

```
user@server:~$ lsblk

sdb                8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─md0              9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 
 └─crypt1        253:0    0  10.9T  0 crypt 
   └─raid-media  253:2    0  18.1T  0 lvm   /media
sdc                8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─md0              9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 
 └─crypt1        253:0    0  10.9T  0 crypt 
   └─raid-media  253:2    0  18.1T  0 lvm   /media
sdd                8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─md0              9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 
 └─crypt1        253:0    0  10.9T  0 crypt 
   └─raid-media  253:2    0  18.1T  0 lvm   /media
sdf                8:80   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─md0              9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 
 └─crypt1        253:0    0  10.9T  0 crypt 
   └─raid-media  253:2    0  18.1T  0 lvm   /media
sdg                8:96   0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md127            9:127  0   7.3T  0 raid1 
 └─crypt2        253:1    0   7.3T  0 crypt 
   └─raid-media  253:2    0  18.1T  0 lvm   /media
sdh                8:112  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md127            9:127  0   7.3T  0 raid1 
 └─crypt2        253:1    0   7.3T  0 crypt 
   └─raid-media  253:2    0  18.1T  0 lvm   /media
```

#### Objective:

I would like to add a third 8TB disk to the 'md127' array without losing the existing data. And since this will grow the array from two drives to three, I would like to reshape the array from RAID-1 to RAID-5 for a net gain of approximately 8TB of free storage.

#### Step 0: Unmount the Logical Volume, and Convert RAID-1 to RAID-5

```
unmount /dev/raid/media
mdadm --grow /dev/md127 --level=5
```

#### Step 1: Add HDD to RAID-5

Supposing the new drive is added as '/dev/sda':

```
$ mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sda
$ mdadm --grow --raid-devices=3 --backup-file=~/md127_grow.bak /dev/md127
```

I understand this can take a *long* time. One can check the progress with `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`.

#### Step 2: Enlarge the physical-drive, volume-group, and filesystem

```
pvresize /dev/mapper/crypt2 
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/raid/media
resize2fs /dev/raid/media
```

I took my notes from [this page](https://upperstage.de/2013/06/25/add-a-new-disk-to-raid-array-and-enlarge-lvm-and-ext4-file-system/) and [this page](http://stevesubuntutweaks.blogspot.com/2015/06/converting-raid1-array-to-raid5-using.html), neither of which consider any encryption. My plan above doesn't consider encryption, except when identifying the physical volume (e.g. '/dev/mapper/crypt2'). I'm guessing that's the only thing I do differently.

I would appreciate any thoughts or comments you may have. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a lot that can go wrong here if the CPU on the NAS is overtaxed or if the system runs out of memory. While the steps you’ve compiled should work *in theory*, I would strongly advise having a backup of the most important data first, even if it is just a temporary upload to a private S3 bucket. I’ve ruined many weekends in my youth while modifying RAID sets in an attempt to “not lose anything” only to lose it all anyway 

Comment: @matigo A backup would be ideal, but my 4Mbps upload speed would take way too long to upload 18TB to the cloud. I looked into it, and was surprised I couldn't just rent a a second NAS for the week to make a temporary on-site backup. Hence why I'm really nervous to pull the trigger.